# Display clipped to unknown boundary in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a drawing in ArcMap. The display of all layers is clipped to an unknown boundary that appears to be made of overlapping circles; see image below; this is a screenshot of mapping visible in the drawing. In the image, the background map should be visible up the extents of the image (and thus a rectangle of mapping should be visible):

[image: This is a screenshot of mapping visible in the drawing. In this image, the background map should be visible up the extents of the image (and thus a rectangle of mapping should be visible)]

This applies to all data types; rasters, feature classes etc. I have tried changing all settings in "Clip Options" in "Data Frame Properties". I cannot find any possible settings to change in "Map Document Properties".

What are the possible causes of this clipped display?

Comment: Are you asking that a basemap needs to be seen in the background? correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: Create a new data frame and copy your layers into, if they still appear clipped it would suggest that the datasets are pre-clipped?

Comment: I have copied the layer to a new dataframe and do not have this clipping issue. I do not understand why but this has solved the problem.